# How prove or disprove $\gcd(\textrm{lcm}[a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}],a_{n+1})=\cdots$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a_{i}, i = 1, 2, \cdots, n, n + 1$ be positive integer numbers, prove or disprove
>   $$\gcd([a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}],a_{n+1})=[\gcd(a_{1},a_{n+1}),\gcd(a_{2},a_{n+1}),\cdots,\gcd(a_{n},a_{n+1})]$$
>   where $[x,y] = \textrm{lcm}[x,y]$

For example
$$a_{1}=1,a_{2}=2,a_{3}=3$$
$$\gcd(\textrm{lcm}[1,2],3)=1$$
$$\textrm{lcm}[\gcd(1,3),\gcd(2,3)]=1$$

also
$$a_{1}=6,a_{2}=9,a_{3}=15$$
then
$$\gcd([6,9],15)=\gcd(18,15)=3$$
$$[\gcd(6,15),\gcd(9,15)]=[3,3]=3$$
so
$$\gcd([6,9],15)=\gcd(18,15)=[\gcd(6,15),\gcd(9,15)]$$
so this such condition.

But for general I think is true.But I can't prove it.

Comment: $\gcd(a_i,a_{n+1})|\gcd([a_1,...,a_n],a_{n+1})$$\quad$$\forall i\in\{1,...,n\}$.

                      If $a|c$ and $b|c$ then $lcm(a,b)|c$

Hence $[\gcd(a_1,a_{n+1}),...,\gcd(a_n,a_{n+1})]$divides $\gcd([a_1,...,a_n],a_{n+1})$

$\Rightarrow \gcd([a_1,...,a_n],a_{n+1})\ge [\gcd(a_1,a_{n+1}),...,\gcd(a_n,a_{n+1})]$

now the other direction.

Comment: Always remember that to prove something like this,you can just consider any arbitrary prime and its exponent and then match the exponents on both sides.If they are equal,so are the two sides.You also want to check out the distributive laws of minimum and maximum functions.They are extremely easy to prove.

Answer (score 3):

For a prime $p$ let $v_p(a)$ be the greatest $n\ge0$ such that $p^n\mid a$.

It's easy to see that $v_p(\gcd(a,b))=\min(v_p(a),v_p(b))$ and $v_p(\text{lcm}(a,b))=\max(v_p(a),v_p(b)).$

Therefore
\begin{align*}&v_p(([a_1,\ldots,a_n],a_{n+1}))\\
&=\min(\max(v_p(a_1),\ldots,v_p(a_n)),v_p(a_{n+1}))\\
&=\max(\min(v_p(a_1),v_p(a_{n+1})), \ldots,\min(v_p(a_n),v_p(a_{n+1})))\\
&v_p([(a_1,a_{n+1}),\ldots,(a_n,a_{n+1})])\end{align*}

So they are equal, because if $v_p(a)=v_p(b)$ for all primes $p$, then $a=b$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_i=\prod_{j=1}^mp_j^{\alpha_{i,j}}$ where $p_j$ are primes, $\alpha_{i,j}$ and $m$ are nonnegative integers. The existences of these parameters are clear. From the definition of gcd and lcm, we can express
$$[a_1,\ldots,a_n]=\prod_{j=1}^m p_j^{\max_{1\le i\le n}\alpha_{i,j}}.$$
It follows that
$$
\gcd([a_1,\ldots,a_n],\,a_{n+1})=\prod_{j=1}^m p_j^{\min\{\alpha_{n+1,j},\,\max_{1\le i\le n}\alpha_{i,j}\}}.
$$
On the other hand, for $1\le j\le n$, we have
$$\gcd(a_i,a_{n+1})=\prod_{j=1}^mp_j^{\min(\alpha_{i,j},\,\alpha_{n+1,j})}.$$
It follows that
$$[\gcd(a_1,a_{n+1}),\,\ldots,\,\gcd(a_n,a_{n+1})]=\prod_{j=1}^mp_j^{\max_{1\le i\le n}\{\min(\alpha_{i,j},\,\alpha_{n+1,j})\}}.$$
Therefore, the original problem is transformed to the following one: prove that
$$
\min\{\alpha_{n+1,j},\,\max_{1\le i\le n}\alpha_{i,j}\}
=\max_{1\le i\le n}\{\min(\alpha_{i,j},\,\alpha_{n+1,j})\}
$$
for each $1\le j\le m$. We can simply it by ignoring the index $j$: write $\beta_i=\alpha_{i,j}$, to prove that
$$
\min\{\beta_{n+1},\,\max_{1\le i\le n}\beta_i\}
=\max_{1\le i\le n}\{\min(\beta_i,\,\beta_{n+1})\}.
$$
Without loss of generality, we can suppose that 
$$
\beta_1\le\cdots\le\beta_k\le \beta_{n+1}\le \beta_{k+1}\le\cdots\le\beta_n,
$$
where $0\le k\le n$.
Then the above problem becomes to prove 
$$
\min\{\beta_{n+1},\,\beta_n\}
=\max\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_k,\beta_{n+1}\}.
$$
Now both sides are equal to the number $\beta_{n+1}$.
This completes the proof.